# How to download mp3 song using youtube_explode_dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, download, mp3

I am using youtube_explode_dart: ^2.0.2 and I want to download the mp3 song but I don't know the process I am not able to find any solution on the internet I don't have any idea as I am new to the development.

Thank you.